# Rails: get an index of selected records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

To learn rails and ruby, I building my first app. I trying to find out how to get a list of records (like index) that matches selection criteria. I want to use this in a view to check a condition on an event (click the save button). In my controller, for example I have:

```
def index
    @annotations = Annotation.all.order(:created_at)
end
```

Now this lists all - how do I restrict it to those annotations where field 1 matches field 1 of the record I save && field 2 matches field 2 the record ? If the count of selected records is greater then 0, then save should not take place. Looks like a callback before_save.

May be said differently: I want to count the number of annotations that where the values of fields 1 and field 2 match.

Comment: Why don't you apply uniqueness constraint

Comment: Is that possible - how would that work? It is conditional uniqueness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply uniqueness validation using [`validates_uniqueness_of`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_uniqueness_of)

```
class Annotation < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of :field_1, scope: [:field_2, :field_3]
end
```

This will not let you save the duplicate record

Comment: Can you explain please as I don't understand

Comment: @DimitrideRuiter `validates_uniqueness_of` will run a `before_save` callback and check if there is any record with same attributes `field_1`, `field_2` and `field_3` if there is rails will not save the new record and will give you warning

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_uniqueness_of

Comment: deepak - have I correctly understood the documentation that, in my case, it should be as follows in the annotation.rb model: 'validates_uniqueness_of :annotation_active, scope: [:annotation_documenttype, :annotation_company]' ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `where`, if I got your question correctly

```
@annotations = Annotation.where(field_1: 'value_you_want_to_search').order(:created_at)
```

Hope that helps!